# Welcoming new players to an MMO game with veteran players who have amassed lots of wealth

Tags: game-design, mmo, economy

One of the main problems in the game Knight Online has been that the servers that have been open for a long time have users with a lot of items.

If I want to join as a new player, it is not logical for me to play the game in those servers because there is no way that I can catch up with the players there (unless I buy a lot of item with real money). Because, in order to obtain "good" items, you have to be in the regions of the game where you will fight with other users, so as a newbie, there is no chance that you can compete with those users.

For example, there is a trend in KO: a new server opens, after ~two years people get quite strong and almost no new user joins the server, and then those strong users just gain more and more items and sell them. Then the server dies practically, with no new blood joining it and old users eventually leaving.

What is a strategy I can use in my MMO to regulate the wealth distribution, or keep it accessible to new players, even when other players have been accumulating wealth for a long time?

Comment: There are lots of different wealth distribution problems in MMOs, and each one will tend to have its own relevant strategies. (See for example this [related question on dealing with misers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/162401/39518) To keep the answers specific and detailed, can we focus your question on the one specific problem you identify, of ensuring new players have a way in, when the servers are dominated by "old money"?

Comment: @DMGregory You are right; let's just focus on the example I gave

Comment: I've taken a stab at focusing your question this way. Please feel free to make correcting edits if I've missed the mark. Adding details about your game mechanics might help you get answers that are useful for your situation. For instance, is PVP competition a major part of your game, or is it mostly PVE? What specific barriers does a new player encounter when playing on a server with wealthy veterans?

Comment: @DMGregory thanks; I have given a bit more detail